# Line-breaking a big equation containing large parentheses

Tags: equations

please help me breaking this equation into two lines.

```
Q_2(T,V)=V^2\left[1+\left( \frac{3}{2}\right)\left( \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon}
F\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{-R_1^2}{\epsilon^2}\right) 
+ \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon}\frac{\alpha^2 B}{\epsilon^4}
F\left(\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{10};\frac{-R_1^{10}}{\epsilon^{10}}\right)\right)
\left(\frac{F_0}{R_1T} \right)^3\right]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass ...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't have a line-break inside a `\left ... \right` group. I would like to suggest that you first replace all instances of `\left` with `\biggl` and all instances of `\right` with `\biggr`. Then it's up to you to decide whether an `align*` or a `multline*` environment is more appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'multline*' environments
\begin{document}
\noindent
With \verb+align*+:
\begin{align*}
Q_2(T,V)=V^2\biggl[ 1+ \frac{3}{2}\biggl\{ 
& \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon} 
F\biggl(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{2};
  \frac{-R_1^2}{\epsilon^2}\biggr) \\
&+ \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon}\frac{\alpha^2 B}{\epsilon^4}
F\biggl(\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{10};
  \frac{-R_1^{10}}{\epsilon^{10}}\biggr)
\biggr\} \biggl(\frac{F_0}{R_1T} \biggr)^{\!\!3}\, \biggr]
\end{align*}


\bigskip\noindent
With \verb+multline*+:
\begin{multline*}
Q_2(T,V)=V^2\biggl[ 1+ \frac{3}{2}\biggl\{ 
 \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon} 
F\biggl(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{2};
  \frac{-R_1^2}{\epsilon^2}\biggr) \\
+ \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon}\frac{\alpha^2 B}{\epsilon^4}
F\biggl(\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{10};
  \frac{-R_1^{10}}{\epsilon^{10}}\biggr)
\biggr\} \biggl(\frac{F_0}{R_1T} \biggr)^{\!\!3}\, \biggr]
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One of possibilities is use of the `multline` math environment defined in `amsmat` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
Q_2(T,V) = V^2g
    \Biggl[1+\left( \frac{3}{2}\right)
    \Biggl(\frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon}F
    \left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{-R_1^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)  \\
    + \frac{2R_1}{3\epsilon}\frac{\alpha^2 B}{\epsilon^4}F
        \left(\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{10};\frac{-R_1^{10}}{\epsilon^{10}}\right)
    \Biggr)
        \left(\frac{F_0}{R_1T} \right)^3
    \Biggr]
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about using `\Big` to size the "outer" pair of parentheses?

Comment: @Mico, this is typing error. Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks. (I've already upvoted your answer, BTW.)

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! I do the same (just now).